# Way to throw exceptions out of several function calls all the way back to main?

Tags: c++, c++11, syntax, exception

What is the "right" way to throw exceptions out of several function calls all the way back to main?

What I'm doing now is for example:

```
void foo() {
    ...
    try {
    ...
    }catch(a1) {
            ...
        throw(a2);
    }
    ...
}

void baz() {
    ...
    try {
        foo();
    }catch(a2) {
        ...
        throw(a3);
    }
    ...
}
```

etc

There's got to be a better way to throw consequently and go out of call stack without catching every exception on the way, is it?

Comment: Just don't catch them, if you don't need to.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ but will it go out all the way back to main?

Comment: Just throw it, let it fall all the way out. Just have a `try`/`catch` wrapping the function call in `main` that eventually results in the `throw`.

Comment: Oh very cool, I didn't know that it works like that. Thanks. Should I close this?

Comment: @kuhaku, this feature is the whole reason for exception existance. Without that, they wouldn't offer much advantage over return codes.

Comment: And it looks like you're also destroying all the information of the exception caught. Like "Who would ever want to know why my code failed?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [except.throw]

> When an exception is thrown, control is transferred to the nearest handler with a matching type (15.3); “nearest” means the handler for which the compound-statement or ctor-initializer following the try keyword was most recently entered by the thread of control and not yet exited.

This means that if an exception is thrown and none of the handlers match its type the exception will propagate up until it finds one or none are found.  You can see this working in this little example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

void foo3() { std::exception e; throw(e); }

void foo2() { try { foo3(); } catch (std::bad_exception){} }

void foo() { foo2(); }


int main()
{
    try
    {
       foo();
    }
    catch (std::exception & e)
    {
        std::cout << "caught in main()";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
caught in main()
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d0bd9cccc739e4f1)</kbd>

Comment: I'm still of the opinion, that the expression "handler" is confusing, as it suggests something up the stack -- like a signal-handler-function. Any explanation (and thus also the standard) should make it obvious, that the current scope is left and zero or more function calls are exited. The expression "handler" should be avoided in favor of something like "catch-block. or even better "enclosing-catch-block". And why would anybody want to change the exception caught.